# Maximum area of pentagon in the quarter circle

Tags: geometry, inequality, analytic-geometry, circles, jensen-inequality

In the figure, quarter arc $AD$ of $x^2+y^2=16$ is given. Points $B,C$ are arbitrary on the arc $AD$ such that $C$ is between $D$ and $B$.

What is the maximum value of $\text{Area}(OABCD)$ ?

[image: figure]

**Notes:**

1. Problem is mine. I have sent for sharing. I hope that you like it and enjoy.
2. I will post my solution(s) after yours. You can use any way for your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle DOC=\alpha$, $\measuredangle COB=\beta$ and $\measuredangle BOA=\gamma$.

Hence, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and since $\sin$ is a concave function on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, by Jensen we obtain:
$$S_{OABCD}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot4^2(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)=$$
$$=8(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)\leq24\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{3}\right)=12.$$
The equality occurs for $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=30^{\circ},$ which gives the answer: $12$.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @MichaelRozenberg . This is one of clear and sharp proofs.

Comment: @scarface Another proof bases on the fact that a continuous function on compact gets on this compact the maximal value.  I believe that you understand that the solution of  AlgorithmsX is total wrong.

Comment: Yes,@MichaelRozenberg . My opinion: AlgorithmX's solution is ''intuitive'' and it is not a clear proof. I can give another proof with using ''isoperimetry''. I think that your other solution method on concept of ''compactness and continuity'' may be same method my concept of isoperimetry.I will send it. If they are different methods, may you post your 2. solution.

Answer (score 2):

Points B and C should divide the circle into three equal arcs. This can be shown by fixing one of the points and letting the other point move around. You maximize the area of the triangle BCD when C divides the arc BD into two equal arcs, because at that point the height of the triangle is maximized. By applying this same argument to triangle ABC, we see that the area of both triangles is maximized when AB=BC=CD. Therefore, the maximum area of the pentagon occurs under the same conditions. This means we have three triangles with two side lengths of 4 and an angle between them of 30°. The entire area is therefore:
$$3*\left(\frac12*4*4*\sin30°\right)=12$$

Answer (score 1):

Isoperimetric inequalities are very elegant theorems in Euclidean geometry. One of them:

**Isoperimetric inequality for cyclic polygons:** If $A_1A_2\dots A_n$ is a cyclic $n$-gon, then area of $A_1A_2\dots A_n$ will be maximum when $n$-gon regular.

We will use this idea in our solution. Let's reflect the figure w.r.t $x$-axis and $y$-axis like following figure.

[image]

We yields a dodecagon. By isoperimetry theorem for cyclic $n$-gon, maximum area of it will be $$\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 12\cdot 4^2\cdot \sin 30^\circ = 48$$ Then, quarter of it is $$\dfrac{48}{4}=12 $$

Comment: In your  dodecagon we can not change $A$, $D$ and else two points. Id est, it's not exactly  an isoperimetry theorem.

Comment: you got it wrong. In my dodecagon, $B$ and $C$ are arbitrary points. In the figure, the docecagon is not regular. This is true. But, it has ability  transform to regular.

Comment: See please on $D$ and $A$. You can not change these points if you wish to solve a starting problem.

Comment: In Original Problem (OP), $A$ and $D$ given stabil points. We will not change positions of $A$ or $D$. Also $B,C$ given arbitrary. Actually I think that this method very understandable.  If have got you a point that can not be understood, I want to answer to it.

Comment: If you don't change $A$ and $D$ than you can not use an  isoperimetry theorem.

Comment: By isoperimetry theorem, in all cyclic dodecagons that circum radius is $4$, regular dodecagon has max area. Isn't it? There is no any reason that we can't take our dodecagon a regular. ( My native language is not English, probably I can't tell correctly. But I'm sure from my solution). Then, I have to take my dodecagon as regular. If OP give to us, for example $|AB|=1$, then I can't it transform to regular. This is a difficulty. But my dodecagon has no any difficulty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57593/discussion-between-scarface-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

Let $C(a,\sqrt{4-a^2})$ and $B(b,\sqrt{4-b^2})$.

Hence, $$S_{OABCD}=f(a,b)=\tfrac{\left(4+\sqrt{4-a^2}\right)a}{2}+\tfrac{\left(\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-a^2}\right)(b-a)}{2}+\tfrac{\sqrt{4-b^2}(4-b)}{2},$$
where $0\leq a\leq b\leq4$.

We see that $f$ is continuous function on $\Phi=\{(a,b)|0\leq a\leq b\leq4\}$, which is compact.

Thus, $f$ gets a maximal value for each $(a_0,b_0)\in\Phi$.

In another hand, if we'll replace $C$ on a middle point of $\smallsmile DB$ or if we'll replace $B$ on  a middle point of  $\smallsmile AC$, then a value of $f$ increases, which says that if $f(a,b)=f(a_0,b_0)$ then $DC=CB=BA$, otherwise we can increase $f$ by previous way, which is contradiction.

Thus, $\max S_{OABCD}=f(a_0,b_0)=12$ (the number $12$ I took from my previous solution)

and we are done.

Comment: Thank for solution @MichaelRozenberg. But I can't see why $$f(a,b)=\dfrac{\left(4+\sqrt{4-a^2}\right)a}{2}+\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-a^2}\right)(b-a)}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{4-b^2}(4-b)}{2}$$ increase? Haven't to find us that critical points with partial derivative of $f$  or, haven't to use us that some algebraic inequalities?

Comment: @scarface I did not say that $f$ increasing function. I said that a value of $f$ increases if we'll change $C$ on a middle point of $\smallsmile DB$.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? $B$ stabil and $C$ on moving arc $BD$. When $C$ goes to midpoint of arc $BD$, then $f$ will be incrase. Therefore $|DC|=|BC|$ . After, $C$ stabil and $D$ on moving arc $AC$. When $B$ goes to midpoint of arc $AC$, then $f$ will be incrase. Therefore $|AC|=|BC|$. Is it?

Comment: @scarface No! It's the  AlgorithmsX's wrong solution. I say only that we can  increase $f$ if $AB=BC=DC$ is not true. Since a maximal value exists (I proved it!), we get that this maximum occurs, when $AB=BC=CD$. See my proof. I explained there all step.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRozenberg . If AlgorithmsX (additionally his solution) prove that the pentagon has a maximum value, then Does his proof complete?

Comment: @scarface  I think no. He say about maximizing of $S_{\Delta DCB}$, but $S_{\Delta ABC}$ changes. He say about maximizing of $S_{\Delta ABC}$, but $S_{\Delta DBC}$ changes. I think the reasoning of AlgorithmsX is total wrong.